# Powershell filter a List by Name and Date

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I need a bit of help... I'm new to powershell and i want to Filter a List (csv). I would love to remove all lines with certain names in it. and cut the list down to the last month. In the script you can see how far i got till now.

```
param(

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,HelpMessage="Enter CSV path(s)")]
    [String[]]$Path = $null
)



if($Path -eq $null) {

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $Dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $Dialog.InitialDirectory = "$InitialDirectory"
    $Dialog.Title = "Select CSV File(s)"
    $Dialog.Filter = "CSV File(s)|*.csv"        
    $Dialog.Multiselect=$true
    $Result = $Dialog.ShowDialog()

    if($Result -eq 'OK') {

        Try {

            $Path = $Dialog.FileNames
        }

        Catch {

            $Path = $null
            Break

        }
    }

    else {


        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Notice: No file(s) selected."
        Break
    }
}

$info=Import-Csv "$path" -Delimiter ';'
$info | Get-Member 
$info | Format-Table
```

as you can see i tryed to link the path to a filebrowser.

Comment: What do you mean by "names"? Do you mean data columns in the file or just the header?

Comment: show contains of your's first file and what output you expect.

Comment: yeah i mean those data columns

Comment: Do not use `format-table` if you want to retrieve properties from that object to do further processing with said properties. It should be for display purposes only.

Comment: sry but i cant show this file... but as a output i would hope to get the same table without a few of the names.

Comment: you need delete all names or just "some names"?

Comment: just some of them...

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of discussion, I will assume that the full pathname of the CSV is in the variable `$InputPath`, and that you want to write the result to a CSV file whose full pathname is in the variable `$OutputPath`. I will also assume that the CSV file contains a column named 'Name', and that the value from the Name column that you want to exclude is in the variable `$ExcludedName`. Given that, you can simply do

```
Import-CSV -Path $InputPath | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $ExcludedName} | Export-CSV -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: And if `$ExcludedName` is an array of multiple names to exclude, do `Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $ExcludedName}` (I think that is what the OP wants to do..) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = Import-Csv "Path" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Names 
$data | export-csv "Path" -Notype
```

This will cut the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by my code,but dont forget that **first row must contains names of column** and delimiter must be ';' and `$nameslist` is array of names that you need delete:

```
$info=Import-Csv "D:\testdir\file2.csv" -Delimiter ';'
$nameslist=@('James','John','andrew')
foreach($i in $info){
    if($nameslist -contains $i.Name){
    $i.Name=""    
    }
    $i|Export-Csv -Path "D:\testdir\file1.csv"  -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 -Append   
}
```

Comment: and do you now how i can remove the complete line where the name is in?

Answer (score 0):

Try it first without using a function:

```bsh
Import-Csv <Filename> | Where-Object {$_.<FieldName> -notlike "*<Value>*"}
```

Also, you might consider something like this:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter CSV path(s)")]
    [String[]]$Path = $(
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        $DialogProperties = @{
            Title       = 'Select CSV File(s)'
            Filter      = 'CSV File(s)|*.csv'
            Multiselect = $True
        }

        $Dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property $DialogProperties
        $Dialog.ShowDialog()

        If ($Result -eq 'OK') {
            $Path = $Dialog.FileNames
        } Else {
            Write-Error 'Notice: No file(s) selected.'
        }
    )
)

Process {
    ForEach ($PathItem in $Path) {
        Import-Csv $PathItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*NotThisOne*" }
    }
}
```